# Tex-style shortcut does not work for Powerpoint 2016 Mac?

Tags: macos, microsoft-powerpoint, latex, tex

I prefer to input math equation with tex-style so that I was very impressed when Microsoft Office implemented the function from Office 2010.

However, I found that I cannot use the tex-style input method for Powerpoint 2016 Mac.

It seems that inserting superscript and subscript still work for Powerpoint 2016.

```
x_1^2 + x_2^3
```

But, other symbols such as below that work for Powerpoint 2010 Win do not work anymore.

```
\sum_i
\pi
\prod_j
```

These still work for Word 2016 Mac so I'm wondering why I cannot use it for Powerpoint.
Does anyone know the way to use Tex-style input for Powerpoint 2016 Mac?